# Could not resolve type with token 0100005d from typeref (expected class 'System.RuntimeFieldHandle' ...) in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My blazor application references a library that is compiled against .net Standard 2.0.

When deploying the app and running, upon accessing this library, I get on the WASM side:

```
Could not resolve type with token 0100005d from typeref (expected class 'System.RuntimeFieldHandle' in assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')
```

This error does not appear when running in Debug mode from Visual Studio, or setting render mode to Server (to omit using WASM).

I suspect it has to do with trimming, some stuff seems to get trimmed away when packing the WASM side.

I added this in my `MyApp.Client.csproj`, but this doesn't change anything:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.Runtime" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I add the following to the method which throws the exception:

```cs
_ = new RuntimeFieldHandle();
```

this line runs through.

What else can I try?

Comment: The problem was that I dynamically downloaded additional assemblies to the WASM side from the server side, and used them with Reflection. I didn't correctly download dependent assemblies. I changed the code so that this Reflection part isn't needed any more, using a better implementation of the functionality, which resolved my problem.